# Running a WAMP Web Server on LAN creates Problems

Tags: networking, lan, webserver, xampp

I have installed [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) on Windows 7, but when I try to access the server with the LAN IP from another PC connected to the same network, the website does not show up, instead throws an error. When I ran the web server on my android device with [kWS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws&hl=en), it works on LAN (I cant use it as is CPU intensive). What can be the cause and how to fix it (XAMPP) ?

Comment: What error? It might give an idea to what the actual issue is

Comment: "Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.1.XX" this was the error by Chrome

Comment: Try Binding the LAN IP again..

Comment: As far as I know, XAMPP does it. If you kown how to bind it manually then Tell me please.

Comment: Happen to have skype running on the system you have xampp on?

Comment: No, Skype was not running at that time. I disabled it as Skype sometimes uses port 80.

Comment: Did you configure the firewall on the PC?   Can you access the webserver from the PC itself (using 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: The Firewall is configured and I can access the Website using `http://127.0.0.1/` and `http://localhost/`